# set button image as setSelected

Tags: ios, swift

i want to change image of button on click.i have a question in application and answer given by app user in YES and NO format .for that i have taken two button with checkbox empty image .i want to change image of button in checkbox_fill if it is clicked and another button set empty checkbox image.how to check if my button already have selected or not ?.my code is as below.

```
@IBAction func btnPainClicked(sender: AnyObject) {


    var selected   : UIImage = UIImage(named:"checkbox_fill.png")!
    var deselected : UIImage = UIImage(named: "checkbox.png")!
    if (sender.tag == 1){

        if(!sender.setSelected){

            btnNO.setImage(deselected, forState:.Normal)
            btnYES.setImage(selected, forState:.Normal)

        }else if(!sender.setSelected){

            btnYES.setImage(deselected, forState: .Normal)
            btnNO.setImage(selected, forState: .Normal)
        }

    }    }
```

i want only one button selected and another will be with empty checkbox image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@IBAction func btnPainClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
let buttonClicked = sender as! UIButton
    if buttonClicked == btnYES {
        btnNO.setImage(deselected, forState:.Normal)
        btnYES.setImage(selected, forState:.Normal)
    } else if buttonClicked == btnNo {
        btnYES.setImage(deselected, forState: .Normal)
        btnNO.setImage(selected, forState: .Normal)
    }
```

i hope it work!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I have a simpler solution for this. In your viewDidLoad, add following code:

```
var selected   : UIImage = UIImage(named:"checkbox_fill.png")!
var deselected : UIImage = UIImage(named: "checkbox.png")!
btnNO.setImage(deselected, forState:.Normal)
btnNO.setImage(selected, forState:.Selected)
btnYES.setImage(deselected, forState:.Normal)
btnYES.setImage(selected, forState:.Selected)
```

and in your func, btnPainClicked

Replace code :

```
 sender.selected=true
   // sender.selected = YES
    if(sender == btnYES) {
        btnNO.selected = false
    }
    else {
        btnYES.selected = false
    }
```

Try this.. It will work like a radio button just like you want... Let me know :)

Comment: it showing can not assign to setSelected in sender.

Comment: Because type of Sender is AnyObject.. Change it  to UIButton.

Comment: sender.selected=true
       // sender.selected = YES
        if(sender == btnYES) {
            btnNO.selected = false
        }
        else {
            btnYES.selected = false
        }   sender.setSlected=YES can not used in swift

Comment: Yes... its same.. You can mark as correct so, others know that this answer helped you.. and follow it when they face same.. :)